# python numpy change array value

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change the value in numpy array, the following was what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np


sdd_type = np.dtype(
    {'names':['name','age','sex'],'formats':['S32','i','S32']})

sdd = np.array(
    [('zhang',35,'M'),('song',34,'F'),('li',45,'M')], dtype=sdd_type
    )

print sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']['age']
#output：array([34]) 

print sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']['age'][0]
#output：34 

sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']['age'][0] = 41
print sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']['age']
#output：array([34])， but expect to be 41
```

How can I change the value to 41?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Boolean or "mask" index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

> As with index arrays, what is returned is a copy of the data, not a view as one gets with slices.

As explained in [Assigning values to indexed arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays), when you're assigning *directly* to an indexing:

> Unlike some of the references (such as array and mask indices) assignments are always made to the original data in the array (indeed, nothing else would make sense!).

But you're not doing that here. While you can assign to `sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']` and modify the original array, assigning to `sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']['age']` is modifying the *copy*.

To understand why, you have to understand how indexing works in Python: a target like `spam[eggs][beans][toast] = value` calls `spam.__getitem__(eggs).__getitem__(beans).__setitem__(toast, value)`; there's no way NumPy can tell that the `sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']` part is being looked up to assign something rather than to access it.

The docs explain how NumPy deals with this in the simple case:

> … a new array is extracted from the original (as a temporary) containing the values at 1, 1, 3, 1, then the value 1 is added to the temporary, and then the temporary is assigned back to the original array.

So, you have to do the same thing manually if you've got multiple `[…]` indexings:

```
tmp = sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song']
tmp[0]['age'] = 41
sdd[sdd['name'] == 'song'] = tmp
```

Note that if you wanted to update everyone named `song` at once instead of just the first (hopefully only?) person named `song`, you could just remove the `[0]` and the same code would work.

But if you really are sure you only have one `song` and want to update only him, you can use the `where`-based solution in [xnx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30294189/908494), which is effectively turning your multiple indexing including a mask index array into a single simple indexing.

Comment: I'm confused by your explanation. If `spam` is a nested Python list (and `eggs,bean,toast` are integers), then it works, so I don't get the point you want to show with that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: That's because Python `list` never makes copies when you index it; as explained in the first section, `np.ndarray` _does_ make copies when you index it with an index array or mask array.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I guess you could argue that NumPy could have been designed to never make copies, and instead make index-array-indexed arrays be a very complicated kind of view into the original array. In the same way, I suppose Python lists could have been designed to not make copies on slicing. But that would be a pretty different design. Once you've decided that index-array indexing makes copies (or that slicing makes copies, as with `list`), there's no way to say "except when on the left side" if there's more than one `[…]` on the left side.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I somewhat misread your statement, but I get it now.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Would it help to include the comparison to simple indexing vs. slicing of Python lists in the answer? There is a lot of information to explain, and I may not have covered it very well…

Comment: Only if you want to. Not for me. I get it now and I just didn't read/think properly, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

@abarnert has explained the reason for this behaviour, but you can also do this to index into your original array instead of a copy:

```
sdd[np.where(sdd['name']=='song')[0][0]]['age']=41
```

Comment: This works if there's guaranteed to be exactly one person named `'song'` (as there is in the example), but otherwise, isn't the `[0]` going to mean only the first one gets updated?

Comment: I think you're right, but it doesn't make sense to update all 'song''s ages in this use case either.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right for this use case. Especially since he explicitly has an equivalent `[0]` in his attempted code. :) So, this may not be the right thing to do in _every_ case, but here it probably is.